# Using collcell package with tabularx X columntype

Tags: tables, tabularx, columns, collcell

I would like to use the `X` column type from the `tabularx` with the `collcell` package.

In the MWE below, I define:

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\TitleColumn}{r}<{\endcollectcell}}% works
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\collectcell\TitleColumn}{X}<{\endcollectcell}}% fails
```

where the `T` applies the `X` column type (does *not compile* and thus is commented out in the MWE) and the `R` (for illustrative purposes) applies the `r` column type (which *works*).

The output has three tables:

1. `R` column type (to ensure syntax is correct)
2. Desired `T` column type (commented out)
3. Desired Result of `T` column type

The error message if table 2 (which uses the `T` columntype) is uncommented is:

> Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (X): `c' used.

[image]

### Notes:

- MWE is greatly simplified such that there is no need to actually use `collcell` here, but needed in actual use case where the `\TitleColumn` and `\ColumnL` macros have more code.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\ColumnL}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\TitleColumn}[1]{#1}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\TitleColumn}{r}<{\endcollectcell}}% works
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\collectcell\TitleColumn}{X}<{\endcollectcell}}% fails

\newcommand*{\TabularContent}{%
    Label 1 Very Long& 62 & 79 \\
    Label 2 Empty Row & \\
    Label 3 Short& 732 & 31 \\
}


\begin{document}
\noindent
1. Column type \verb|R| (equivalent to centered \verb |r| column) works fine:
\par\smallskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Rll@{}}
    \TabularContent
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\noindent
2. Column type \verb|T| (equivalent to centered \verb |c| column) FAILS 
\par(commented out):
\par\smallskip\noindent
%\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Tll@{}}%% <--- How to get this to work
%    \TabularContent
%\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\noindent
3. Desired result of above \verb|T| column type is the \verb|X| column type::
\par\smallskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xll@{}}
    \TabularContent
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the braces around the `X` and it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\ColumnL}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\TitleColumn}[1]{#1}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\TitleColumn}r<{\endcollectcell}}% works
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\collectcell\TitleColumn}X<{\endcollectcell}}% doesn't fail

\newcommand*{\TabularContent}{%
    Label 1 Very Long& 62 & 79 \\
    Label 2 Empty Row & \\
    Label 3 Short& 732 & 31 \\
}


\begin{document}
\noindent
1. Column type \verb|R| (equivalent to centered \verb |r| column) works fine:
\par\smallskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Rll@{}}
    \TabularContent
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\noindent
2. Column type \verb|T| (equivalent to centered \verb |c| column) FAILS no longer
\par(commented out):
\par\smallskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Tll@{}}%% <--- Now we got this to work
    \TabularContent
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\noindent
3. Desired result of above \verb|T| column type is the \verb|X| column type::
\par\smallskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xll@{}}
    \TabularContent
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```